# how to get information from blue ray disc player of google tv

Tags: android, google-tv

I am trying to develop an app for Google TV, which will detect the media items from disc player and show or play the items through the app.
Is there any api to retrieve the contents from CD/DVD.
Kindly help.

Sudipta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, sorry. The majority of Google TV devices do not have "CD/DVD". You are welcome to ask the device manufacturer for your particular device if they have some sort of SDK add-on that offers what you seek.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for valuable suggestion.